# concatenate numpy 1D array in columns

Tags: arrays, numpy, concatenation

I have two numpy arrays:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([4, 5, 6])
```

and I want to concatenate them into two columns like,

```
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

is there any way to do this without transposing or reshaping the arrays?

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/62109123/901925

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([4, 5, 6])
c = np.concatenate((a[np.newaxis, :], b[np.newaxis, :]), axis = 0).T
```

And you get :

`c = array([[1, 4],
            [2, 5],
            [3, 6]])`

Best,